# Laravel 5 Routing Object Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I ussualy using Laravel 4 and now Im trying to learn Laravel 5

there's problem on Naming Controller Routes :

i had route like :

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@viewHome', 
    'as' => 'home'
]);

Route::get('/events', [
        'uses' => 'EventController@viewEvent', 
        'as' => 'event'
    ]);
```

when i run route as 'home' (localhost/laravel/) its work perfectly

but when i run route as 'event' (localhost/laravel/events): Object not found!
[image]

and i already make sure that viewEvent method running right by swap it like this:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'EventController@viewEvent', 
    'as' => 'home'
]);

Route::get('/events', [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@viewHome', 
        'as' => 'event'
    ]);
```

i can run viewEvent but i cant run viewHome

any problem with my code?

======================== SOLVED =============================

with help @DamienPirzy and i realize when i disable /public/ folder i think i must make .htaccess out to main folder too :)

thanks all for fast response :) Problem Solved

Comment: `(localhost/laravel/event)` but your routes declares "events",  plural

Comment: just typo i run it with localhost/laravel/events @DamienPirsy

Comment: Do you have the .htaccess properly setup? Does it work if you go to `laravel/index.php/events`?

Comment: @DamienPirsy wow its work but how can i fix it?

Comment: @DamienPirsy i already solve it thanks btw :)

Answer (score 6):

Put this htaccess into public folder. make sure you have apache mod rewrite working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: tried to add rewrite rule in this code but gives me "Object not found"   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783056/https-laravel-using-htaccess-public

Answer (score 2):

i saw in routes.php

```
Route::get('/events', [
        'uses' => 'EventController@viewEvent', 
        'as' => 'event'
    ]);
```

But u run

```
localhost/laravel/event
```

Should run

```
localhost/laravel/events
```

Comment: just typo i run it with localhost/laravel/events

Comment: Try add this @GandhyOnly
Route::get('/events',  'EventController@viewEvent');

Answer (score 2):

Could you check on .htaccess file?
Cuz that screen error is from Apache. The request didn't go to Laravel App.

or check mod_rewrite is enabled,or not?

Comment: Cool! i got the same problem and tried to fix this for an hour, you save my life.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the htacess file from the public folder and paste it into the root directory. It should solve the problem, also check the spelling of all routes; they must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

try to change .htaccess file to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add index.php after project name like **localhost/cms/index.php/**
By doing this your all routes are working

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```