# HTTPS: Laravel using .htaccess (public/)

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, https

I'm trying to include https in my Laravel Project without using godaddy only using `htaccess` and not that big deal since I'm using `proxypass` from my SSL certified website that will pass to my laravel project.

I just need to make my laravel project to https.

So I tried to add this code to my .htaccess located at `public/`

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myproject.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here's my `public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATED**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]

**My httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/e-wallet-frontend/public"
ServerName localhost

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/e-wallet-frontend/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog "logs/frontendewallet.com-error_log"
CustomLog "logs/frontendewallet.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

the `HTTPS` appears but the browser says `Object not Found` is there something wrong with my htaccess?

Comment: The `.htaccess` you show doesn't include the redirect you say you added - is it there, and if so where?  What does your browser's dev tools show, is the redirect working? You are redirecting requests from port 80 to 443 - did you update your Apache config to handle requests on that new port?

Comment: Check the updated post

Comment: If you are getting a 404 it means Apache/SSL are working fine, right? Just the page isn't there.  Have you [set up Laravel auth stuff](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#introduction)? Do other pages work?

Comment: Hello, I didn't touch my `config/auth.php` is there anything I need to do with that? Yes the HTTPS works fine but the route that I'm trying to navigate gives me an error like this `Object not found`

Comment: I'll ask again, have you [set up Laravel auth stuff](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#introduction)? The docs I keep linking to describe how to set up authentication in Laravel :-)

Comment: I'm using middle ware for my users

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myproject.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is the code I have on my multiple Laravel projects.